# iOS 9 scroll UITextView to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

In iOS 7 and/or 8, scrolling my `UITextView` to the top programmatically works as intended in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.someTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
```

Now it just loads to my some other frame. My guess is it's loading to my contentOffset `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 65, 0)`

How do I make this work >=iOS9?

Note: I've already tried placing in `viewDidAppear` with no results

---

**EDIT** The issue occurs in circumstances when my `UITextView` text is greater than the height of it's view. I use `UIEdgeInsets` because the view is presented modally, and is somewhat larger than the screen bounds. However, the `scrollRangeToVisible` still works iOS 7/8 but not iOS9, in this circumstance

Comment: Did you try with `[self. someTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];`. Or using in `willLayoutsubviews ` ?

Comment: Neither work in my circumstance.

Comment: Place in `viewDidLayoutSubviews ` ?

Comment: @anhtu the previous comment rectified the issue at hand. please post as an answer to receive credit due. Thank you, should have been the first thing I tried, it's always the first thing you should have tried.

Comment: Do you mean you solved this problem? How? `[self. someTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]` or `willLayoutsubviews `

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to place your code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: This is also what I ended up doing. Sadly, it appears to render incorrectly first briefly and then corrects itself. Thank you Apple for decreasing the quality of everyone's apps in one fell swoop.

Comment: Was using `scrollRangeToVisible:` before (which has no `animated:` parameter), but changing it to `scrollRectToVisible:` as @thekenner33 suggests (and passing `NO` for `animated:`) resolves the initial rendering issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on iOS 9, and this workaround fixed it:

```
@property (nonatomic) bool workaroundIOS9Bug;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  self.workaroundIOS9Bug = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 9.0;
}


-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  if (self.workaroundIOS9Bug) {
    self.textView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    self.workaroundIOS9Bug = false;
  }
}
```

Meaning, it's only necessary to do this extra clearing of contentOffset the first time that subviews are being laid out. Doing it all the time would be a pain when the user rotates the screen or is doing other stuff with the view.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
[self.someTextView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, x, x) animated:YES]
```

where `x` is some nonzero width? It seems that `scrollRectToVisible:` scrolls farther up than `scrollRangeToVisible:`.

Comment: in your example, it would be `self.someTextView.layer` in order to use that reference, however it does not work in my circumstance. Please edit it, just so you don't accrue down votes. Or complete the method by adding `animated` to the syntax