# content offset doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to set the content offset in my uiscrollview. I have tried the following, and none of it works. None of the following affect my scrollView in any way, it simple appears on the screen as normal.:

```
 let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height / 2)
 self.scrollView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
```

and:

```
 self.scrollView.contentOffset.y = self.view.frame.size.height / 2
```

and:

```
 self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2)
```

and:

```
 self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.frame.size.height / 2)
```

I have a scroll view that is 2 times the height of my view. They are essentially separated into 2 different view that I can page between. I want the scrollview to start on the bottom part.

Comment: Where did you place these lines?

Comment: in the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try them in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Ref: [iOS 9 scroll UITextView to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238546/ios-9-scroll-uitextview-to-top/32262025#32262025)

Comment: You sir, saved me!

Answer (score 0):

I was really scratching my head when I found that setting scrollView.contentOffset to any value was not working. Eventually I realized that I was calling the scrollView delegate message 'scrollViewDidScroll' to manage scroll dragging peculiarities.

It turns out that 'scrollViewDidScroll' is called whenever the scrollView contentOffset is changed, and my code to manage drag issues was changing the contentOffset. I just made a 'BOOL isDragging' variable to only make changes to the contentOffset when dragging:

```
private var isDragging : Bool = false
private var initialContentOffset = CGPoint.zero
public func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    isDragging = true
    ...
}


public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // need to keep track if we are dragging with isDragging
        // since this 'scrollViewDidScroll' API is called with ANY contentOffset change
    if (isDragging == true){
        // do stuff to contentOffset to manage dragging peculiarities
        ...
    }
}

public func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    
    if (decelerate == false){
        scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView)
    }
}

public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView)
}

public func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    isDragging = false
}
```